# Using the AWS CDK bundler with resolved URL attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm using the CDK bundler to build my static files (HTML, JavaScript), and upload them to an S3 bucket which is part of my deployment. However, my source files need to know the final URL they will be deployed at, since that will affect internal URLs. Therefore I try to pass in an environment variable derived from the API Gateway's URL.

```
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'restApi');
const staticRoute = api.root.addResource('static');
new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployWebsite', {
    sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset("./path/to/source/files", {
        bundling: {
            image: cdk.DockerImage.fromRegistry("node:latest"),
            command: [
                'bash', '-c', `
            cd /asset-input \
            && npm install \
            && npm run build \
            && mv build/* /asset-output
    `,
            ],
            environment: {
                'PUBLIC_URL': api.urlForPath(staticRoute.path)
            }
        },
    })],
    destinationBucket: this.websiteBucket,
});
```

However, in practise this code doesn't work, because it just interpolates the CloudFormation tokens into the `PUBLIC_URL` variable, and I get something like `'https://${Token[TOKEN.380]}.execute-api.us-east-1.${Token[AWS.URLSuffix.10]}/${Token[TOKEN.399]}/static/'`, which obviously won't work. How can I resolve these tokens to actual string components **at build time**, which is when I compile my static content?

Answer (score 1):

If you say build time, do you mean before the stack is executed? Because that is impossible. CDK uses these tokens, because it is not possible to have these values before you actually deploy the stack.

There are several options to work around this, you could for example split up the stacks, deploy the stack with the API GW and use the URL of the API as a parameter in your second stack. You could either just pass the URL along as a parameter, or you could combine the CDK with the aws-sdk in order to retrieve the necessary parameter. You could either retrieve it from the service itself, or define it as an output in the first stack and retrieve it that way.

Comment: `Fn::ImportValue` will also produce a token.

Comment: At build time, yes. You could work around that by using the aws-sdk to retrieve the output value.

Comment: Sure. My point is that using an import or a stack parameter will not solve the issue, assuming you're referring to cloudformation parameters.

Comment: I just made the comment in order to help someone out who is less experienced and comes across this :)

Comment: Your statement about using an import to avoid copy-pasting is incorrect, though. It will lead to the same exact error OP is facing in the question.

Comment: Yes I do mean before the stack is executed. I know this is impossible literally but I'm hoping for a solution that would give the same solution but I'm flexible on the actual method used. Your idea of splitting it into two stacks and importing seems good but it sounds like that won't actually work?

Comment: It will, you'll just have to use the aws-sdk. I'll update the answer in order to reflect this.

Comment: "You could either retrieve it from the service itself, or define it as an output in the first stack and retrieve it that way." - this is still wrong, a stack output will be an unresolved token. The API GW URL will also be an unresolved token during synth.

Comment: You'll have to execute the first stack before executing the second stack. There cannot be an URL before it has been created.

Comment: It will still be a token, it doesn't matter if you execute it afterwards. Tokens are resolved during deployment, after synth.